# Secure Solr instance on AWS server using http basic authentication

Tags: apache, solr, amazon-web-services, basic-authentication, bitnami

I am trying to secure an AWS server with http basic auth.
Having put an .htaccess file pointing to an .htpasswd file in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs it only secures the http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.x-x-x.compute.amazonaws.com page. The subdirectory http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.x-x-x.compute.amazonaws.com/solr is still accessible without authentication.

I tried to put the .htaccess file in the following places but it did not secure the access:
/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/
/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr-webapp/webapp (where admin.html for the GUI)

So my question is where to put the .htaccess file to secure the GUI access and also only allow http basic auth-protected queries on its cores.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I cannot protect it via htaccess, instead, http base auth is provided by Jetty configuration as explained in [Jetty realm example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity).